# Set-Cookie Header not being returned on linux server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a weird problem in a razor web service that I built recently.
I'm querying two endpoints in my application. The first endpoint sends some credentials to obtain an authentication token and the second endpoint is a graphql endpoint which needs this token for authentication.

When I post to the first endpoint I'm getting the expected token on both windows and linux and also receive the *Set-Cookie* header with the following content:

> KC_RESTART=; Version=1; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/auth/realms/sides/; HttpOnly

The problem is occuring when I'm trying to query the graphql endpoint when the service is running on my linux server.

If I'm running my application locally on my windows machine over http I'm receiving a *Set-Cookie* header in the response with the following content:

> JSESSIONID=xxxxx; Path=/sidexgql; Secure; HttpOnly

But if I'm trying to use the same application hosted on a linux server through an nginx reverse proxy I'm not receiving the *Set-Cookie* header in the response and cannot read the data I need, because I'm not authorized.

The nginx config for the server looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name testserver;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/testserver.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/testserver.error.log;
    location / {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" always;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT" always;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Accept, Accept-CH, Accept-Charset, Accept-Datetime, Accept-Encoding, 
        Accept-Ext, Accept-Features, Accept-Language, Accept-Params, Accept-Ranges, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials,
        Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Expose-Headers,
        Access-Control-Max-Age, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method, Age, Allow, Alternates, Authentication-Info,
        Authorization, C-Ext, C-Man, C-Opt, C-PEP, C-PEP-Info, CONNECT, Cache-Control, Compliance, Connection, Content-Base,
        Content-Disposition, Content-Encoding, Content-ID, Content-Language, Content-Length, Content-Location, Content-MD5,
        Content-Range, Content-Script-Type, Content-Security-Policy, Content-Style-Type, Content-Transfer-Encoding,
        Content-Type, Content-Version, Cookie, Cost, DAV, DELETE, DNT, DPR, Date, Default-Style, Delta-Base, Depth,
        Derived-From, Destination, Differential-ID, Digest, ETag, Expect, Expires, Ext, From, GET, GetProfile, HEAD,
        HTTP-date, Host, IM, If, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Range, If-Unmodified-Since, Keep-Alive,
        Label, Last-Event-ID, Last-Modified, Link, Location, Lock-Token, MIME-Version, Man, Max-Forwards, Media-Range,
        Message-ID, Meter, Negotiate, Non-Compliance, OPTION, OPTIONS, OWS, Opt, Optional, Ordering-Type, Origin, 
        Overwrite, P3P, PEP, PICS-Label, POST, PUT, Pep-Info, Permanent, Position, Pragma, ProfileObject, Protocol,
        Protocol-Query, Protocol-Request, Proxy-Authenticate, Proxy-Authentication-Info, Proxy-Authorization,
        Proxy-Features, Proxy-Instruction, Public, RWS, Range, Referer, Refresh, Resolution-Hint, Resolver-Location,
        Retry-After, Safe, Sec-Websocket-Extensions, Sec-Websocket-Key, Sec-Websocket-Origin, Sec-Websocket-Protocol,
        Sec-Websocket-Version, Security-Scheme, Server, Set-Cookie, Set-Cookie2, SetProfile, SoapAction, Status,
        Status-URI, Strict-Transport-Security, SubOK, Subst, Surrogate-Capability, Surrogate-Control, TCN, TE,
        TRACE, Timeout, Title, Trailer, Transfer-Encoding, UA-Color, UA-Media, UA-Pixels, UA-Resolution,
        UA-Windowpixels, URI, Upgrade, User-Agent, Variant-Vary, Vary, Version, Via, Viewport-Width,
        WWW-Authenticate, Want-Digest, Warning, Width, X-Content-Duration, X-Content-Security-Policy,
        X-Content-Type-Options, X-CustomHeader, X-DNSPrefetch-Control, X-Forwarded-For, X-Forwarded-Port,
        X-Forwarded-Proto, X-Frame-Options, X-Modified, X-OTHER, X-PING, X-PINGOTHER, X-Powered-By, X-Requested-With" always;
        
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5140/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:5140;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Can anybody explain why I'm not receiving the same response headers if my application is running on a linux server?

Comment: Check nginx setup to forward cookies. Probably cookie contains a local path of the backend host but it must contain a full host frontend url. Thus browser rejects such cookie.

Comment: @aepot I added the nginx config for the server. The Set-Cookie header was included for the reverse proxy so I'm not sure if this is the problem.

Comment: Inspect the traffic with Fiddler or with browser dev tools. I'm not sure if the header not there but expect that there's a wrong header which is rejected by browser. Nginx can fix it if you make some script.